# ADLS Gen2 REST API giving error with status code 400

Tags: azure, rest, postman, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I was going through the list of REST API's for Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 and facing problems when i call the api's from CLI/Postman.

i just started with simple get request [path list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list)  api.
[image: Postman get request]

But response am getting as below

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidHeaderValue","message":"The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.\nRequestId:ecb96bb0-501f-0030-2578-65cf12000000\nTime:2020-07-29T07:20:35.6240747Z"}}
```

After searching found sample code to  [create directory/file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1185015f-7c9c-4498-9624-12f24d6ac6ee/sample-code-to-access-gen2-rest-api?forum=AzureDataLake) and tried to create directory but got response like

**Put Request**

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "x-ms-version: 2020-07-29" -H "content-length: 0" -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://$AccountName.dfs.core.windows.net/mydata?resource=filesystem"
```

**Response for the above request**

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   202  100   202    0     0    115      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   115HTTP/1.1 400 The value         
for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
Content-Length: 202
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Server: Windows-Azure-HDFS/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 8d615c77-001f-0070-2b79-65c82a000000
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2020 07:25:54 GMT

{"error":{"code":"InvalidHeaderValue","message":"The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.\nRequestId:8d615c77-001f-0070-2b79-65c82a000000\nTime:2020-07-29T07:25:55.9048230Z"}}
```

For authentication i am using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantID}}/oauth2/token?` and then capturing the bearer token in Test section using this below code.

```
pm.test(pm.info.requestName, () => {
    pm.response.to.not.be.error;
    pm.response.to.not.have.jsonBody('error');
});
pm.globals.set("bearerToken", pm.response.json().access_token);

pm.test(pm.info.requestname, ()=>{
    pm.response.to.not.be.error;
    pm.response.to.not.have.jsonBody('error');
})
pm.globals.set('BearerToken',("Bearer ").concat(pm.response.json().access_token));
```

can anyone tell me where and what is going wrong?

---

---

## Updating question as requested with Screenshots.

After doing so many trials figured out[filesystem-list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/filesystem/list) i am getting response but for [path-list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list) getting error saying `AuthorizationPermissionMismatch` with `403` status code.

### FileSystem List:

[image: FileSystem-list]

### Path List:

[image: Path-List]

#### Headers for the failed one

[image]

Comment: What is the resource for your token? It should be `https://storage.azure.com`

Comment: IN resource was using `https://management.azure.com/` and tried with your suggestion also but the response is same.

Comment: Your resource should be `https://storage.azure.com`. Did I say this before? Why yes, yes I did

Comment: @HongOoi tried with `https://storage.azure.com` still the same response.
`{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationPermissionMismatch","message":"This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.\nRequestId:8cb9734d-f01f-0090-19b8-6c4bb3000000\nTime:2020-08-07T12:44:57.8346082Z"}}`

Comment: @HongOoi tell me how come it is working for `file system - list` API ?

Answer (score 1):

**Update 0807:**

Suppose you have already created a `Service principal`. Then follow the steps below:

Step 1: In azure portal, your ADLS Gen2 -> click on the "Access Control" -> click "Add" -> click "Add role assignment" -> in the "Add role assignment" popup, select "Contributor" for Role; then select your Service Principal name; at last, click Save button. The screenshot as below(Note, it may take a few minutes to take effect.):

[image]

Then add the "Storage Blob Data Reader" role:

[image]

Step 2: In postman, input this url for get request: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token`.

Then in Body -> select "form-data", and input the following keys and values:

```
grant_type:  client_credentials
client_id :  xxxxxxx
client_secret: xxxxxx
resource: https://storage.azure.com/
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

At last, you can call the ADLS Gen2 rest api(note: the x-ms-date should be set to today). The screenshot as below:

[image]

---

**Update 0730:** How to use SAS token for authentication.

1.Nav to azure portal -> your "data lake storage gen2 account" -> then in the left pane, click on "Shared access signature" -> then select proper values -> at last, click the "Generate SAS and connection string" button. And please refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

2.Open postman, and there're something you should note:

1.for SAS token, please replace the first ? with &. Then place the SAS token at the end of the url.
2.if you're using SAS token, then you no need to use Authorization in the request header, please remove it.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Please let me know if you still have more issues.

---

**Original answer:**

There're several errors in your request.

Take [Path - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list) for example, the `x-ms-version` should be `2018-11-09`; and you should add the `x-ms-date` in the request header; and please remove the `Content-Length` in the request header.

I test it at my side, it works ok. Here is the test result:

[image]

Please let me know if you still have more issues.

Comment: made changes as suggested by but still getting error `{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationInfo",
        "message": "Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.\nRequestId:2ca97766-701f-0027-438d-656619000000\nTime:2020-07-29T09:49:04.0210844Z"
    }
}`

Comment: @BenBean, can you please let me know how do you generate the authentication? it's the authentication issue.

Comment: If you see the postman screenshot, in first file i am authenticating and saving the bearer token in variable. And passing the variable in the next request( 2nd file). If i hover on the variable {{bearerToken}} it is showing the value.

Comment: @BenBean, I mean how do you get the original bearer token?

Comment: If am doing anything wrong in postman then why am i not getting any response here also `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list#code-try-0`

Comment: any help on this

Comment: @BenBean, do you mind using `sas token` for authentication? it's quite simple to be generated.

Comment: and for the rest api "Try it" button, I did a test, no response. I guess there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do? Instead of bearer token for just need to add SAS token in authentication right?

Comment: @BenBean, can you log into azure portal, and nav to your "data lake gen2" account?

Comment: Yes i can access “data lake gen2“

Comment: @BenBean, please see the updated section in the answer:).

Comment: Using SAS token worked but why it is giving error with bearer token? Any idea

Comment: @BenBean, I'll give it a try, and update you later.

Comment: @BenBean, do you know some programming language like c#?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218860/discussion-between-ben-bean-and-ivan-yang).