# How to List contents of directory in azure data lake gen2 using sas url at directory level to get metadata for contents of folder

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-sas

[The Error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwUFD.png)

I tried to follow this link:
[List folder in Azure Gen2 storage account with sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70772879/list-folder-in-azure-gen2-storage-account-with-sas)

following above link from postman and I am getting authorization error. what else should be added in header?

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in my environment; I just add below details. Now it’s working fine in postman

Go to azure storage account gen2 -> click on access control -> click on add ->add role assignment and select contributor as role, then select your service principle and save.

[image: Ref1]

**SAS token Syntax**

```
https://<StorageURL>/<Container>?directory=<DirectoryName>&restype=container&comp=list&<SASToken>
```

For more information follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148634/adls-gen2-rest-api-giving-error-with-status-code-400) thread by Ivan Yang and this reference [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOcXoE4QJNI&list=LL&index=1&t=261s)